# Eclipse formatter: how do I format arrays in annotations

Tags: java, eclipse, annotations, eclipse-formatter

I'm using Hibernate Validation (JSR 303) and I'm trying to tame the Eclipse formatter to have nested annotations on seperate lines. Example:

```
    @DefinedParametersMatchesResultPresence.List( {
    @DefinedParametersMatchesResultPresence( measurement = Measurement.penetrationLength ),
    @DefinedParametersMatchesResultPresence( measurement = Measurement.coneResistance ), @DefinedParametersMatchesResultPresence( measurement = Measurement.depth ),
    @DefinedParametersMatchesResultPresence( measurement = Measurement.electricalConductivity ),

} )
```

However.. I can't get the annotations in the `DefinedParametersMatchesResultPresence.List` on a new line when running format. Additionally, the formatter does not comply to my max line length and wrap to a new line.

I'm using:

> Version: Neon.2 Release (4.6.2)
>    Build id: 20161208-0600

Comment: Some formatting you just have to do yourself. I know of no IDE that formats everything perfectly; you always have to do some tweaking.

Answer (score 1):

Although the formatting concerns annotations, the array formatting also applies. After setting array formatting correctly it works as expected.

Next: its also possible to use the `@Repeatable` annotation when using your own annotations which lead to a nicer